# Boonex extra top menu

Tags: menu

I am creating a site using boonex 7.0. I need  add an extra menu  at the top of the "Top Menu Location".
I am having the portion  with .

```
 __extra_top_menu__ ... Kindly any one help  me to  get the extra menu  at the top of Main menu (Top Menu) from the admin side ...
```